# What mathematical function can I use to add a loop to my roller coaster function?

Tags: matlab

I posted here a few days ago about my project that I am working on. I have decided to make a "dueling dragons" rollercoaster. The coasters are on different planes so the points that they intercept don't actually crash in my head. I have plotted the x,y values and feel comfortable in how they look. I am having the challenge of adding other components, say a loop, a flat line, smaller hills etc. If I wanted to go into a loopy loop after the first function pictured, what would be the best way to do this seamlessly, without breaks in the tracks or a function that doesn't transition smoothly. I have attached my code below with an image of the graph I have produced. Again, I would like some feedback on how to seamlessly transition to this complicated function to another. I had an idea of using Eulers method but have not made success with this method

[image]

```
**%Dualing dragons 
 
%x with respect to time?
x = 0:.01:8;
y = 120*cos(x)+.05*(exp(x))+.003*(-exp(x))-100*sin(x)
 
xx = 0:.01:8;
yy= spline(x,y,xx);
plot(x,y)
hold on
 
%trying to combine function 
x2 = 0:.01:8;
y2 = -120*cos(x2)-.05*(exp(x2))-.003*(exp(x2))+100*sin(x2);
plot(x2,y2);
hold on**
```

Comment: It depends on what you want the shape of your loop to be. To make one function transition smoothly into another, you need to make sure that `y` and the derivatives of `y` with respect to `x` are the same at the point of intersection.

Comment: Is your question "How can my program figure out a mathematical function that would smoothly loop?" or "What mathematical function would smoothly loop?" Because if it's the latter, your question is [off-topic](/help/on-topic) here. If it's the former, [edit] your question to include your attempt at figuring out the function in your program. Please take the [tour], read the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), and provide a [mre] that reproduces your _specific_ problem. Welcome to SO!

Comment: Sorry I am new here, Ill try to make those changes @PranavHosangadi , just trying to get some ideas!